# How to install version 4.11 of the package texinfo?

Tags: package-management

I need to install the package texinfo version 4.11 that I downloaded from http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/texinfo/ and unpacked (folder texinfo-4.11).

I already installed packages with the 'sudo apt-get install' command in the terminal. However, this does not work with 'sudo apt-get install texinfo-4.11' in the correct terminal location. The following error messages appear:

E: Unable to locate package texinfo-4.11

E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'texinfo-4.11'

Comment: Depending on your version of Ubuntu, it may not be available. You might have to compile from source.

Comment: what is your ubuntu version?

Comment: Ubuntu Precise has version 4.13 of `texinfo`, and Ubuntu Trusty has version `5.2.0`. Are you sure you *really* need an older version?

Comment: There are errors when compiling the toolchain of my linux-control-unit. The manufacturer told me to use texinfo 4.11. I have ubuntu 13.10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't install software like that unless it's "packaged" for your system. You might want to see if someone has already created a package for Ubuntu. Otherwise, you'll have to compile and install manually. It isn't difficult, but also not as convenient as using an installer.

For basic installation instructions, look in texinfo-4.11.tar.bz/texinfo-4.11/INSTALL.

Comment: The compilation is delivering an error message:  zulu@E131x-series:~/LCU1/texinfo-4.11$ ./configure
bash: ./configure: Permission denied